# Not able to load tensorflow JS model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I have already converted keras model to tensorflowjs model. But when I am trying to load the same in browser it gives error which says that

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: block1_conv1_1/kernel.

I have used transfer learning on vgg16 model in keras.

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using to load the model in tensorflow.js ?

Comment: code i am using to load the model is                                                        
model = await tf.loadModel('http://localhost:8080/plant_diseases/model.json',strict=false);

Comment: Can you please update the question with the keras model ? There is an open issue related to the question: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/755